# Pandas, how to find complementary time ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, transform

I have a dataframe with times when the court is not free:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'court_name': 'Court 1', 'reserved_fr': '2021-11-15T08:00:00', 'reserved_to': '2021-11-15T12:00:00'}, 
        {'court_name': 'Court 1', 'reserved_fr': '2021-11-15T15:00:00', 'reserved_to': '2021-11-15T16:00:00'}, 
        {'court_name': 'Court 1', 'reserved_fr': '2021-11-15T16:00:00', 'reserved_to': '2021-11-15T21:00:00'}, 
        {'court_name': 'Court 2', 'reserved_fr': '2021-11-15T20:00:00', 'reserved_to': '2021-11-15T21:00:00'}
    ]
)


|    | court_name   | reserved_fr         | reserved_to         |
|---:|:-------------|:--------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 | Court 1      | 2021-11-15T08:00:00 | 2021-11-15T12:00:00 |
|  1 | Court 1      | 2021-11-15T15:00:00 | 2021-11-15T16:00:00 |
|  2 | Court 1      | 2021-11-15T16:00:00 | 2021-11-15T21:00:00 |
|  3 | Court 2      | 2021-11-15T20:00:00 | 2021-11-15T21:00:00 |
```

If each court working time is from 7 am to 11 pm, I would like to know when the court is free.

For example courts are free:

```
Court 1     2021-11-15 07:00:00   2021-11-15 08:00:00
Court 1     2021-11-15 12:00:00   2021-11-15 15:00:00
Court 1     2021-11-15 21:00:00   2021-11-15 23:00:00
Court 2     2021-11-15 07:00:00   2021-11-15 20:00:00
Court 2     2021-11-15 21:00:00   2021-11-15 23:00:00
```

How to transform dataframe to the another dataframe in format above?

Answer (score 3):

Solution without defined exact days for times between `7:00` and `23:00` is:

```
#reshape for hours to one column date
L = [pd.date_range(s,e, freq='H') 
     for s, e in df[['reserved_fr','reserved_to']].to_numpy()]
df['date'] = L

df1 = df.explode('date').drop_duplicates(['court_name','date'])
print (df1)
  court_name          reserved_fr          reserved_to                date
0    Court 1  2021-11-15T08:00:00  2021-11-15T12:00:00 2021-11-15 08:00:00
0    Court 1  2021-11-15T08:00:00  2021-11-15T12:00:00 2021-11-15 09:00:00
0    Court 1  2021-11-15T08:00:00  2021-11-15T12:00:00 2021-11-15 10:00:00
0    Court 1  2021-11-15T08:00:00  2021-11-15T12:00:00 2021-11-15 11:00:00
0    Court 1  2021-11-15T08:00:00  2021-11-15T12:00:00 2021-11-15 12:00:00
1    Court 1  2021-11-15T15:00:00  2021-11-15T16:00:00 2021-11-15 15:00:00
1    Court 1  2021-11-15T15:00:00  2021-11-15T16:00:00 2021-11-15 16:00:00
2    Court 1  2021-11-15T16:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 17:00:00
2    Court 1  2021-11-15T16:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 18:00:00
2    Court 1  2021-11-15T16:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 19:00:00
2    Court 1  2021-11-15T16:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 20:00:00
2    Court 1  2021-11-15T16:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 21:00:00
3    Court 2  2021-11-15T20:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 20:00:00
3    Court 2  2021-11-15T20:00:00  2021-11-15T21:00:00 2021-11-15 21:00:00
```

---

```
#added missing values between 7:00 and 23:00 if not exist
def f(x):
    r = pd.date_range(x.index.min().normalize() + pd.Timedelta('7H'),
                      x.index.max().normalize() + pd.Timedelta('23H'), freq='H')
    return x.reindex(r)
        
    
s = df1.set_index('date').groupby('court_name')['court_name'].apply(f)

#create groups for missing values and aggregate first with last
mask = s.notna()
df = (mask.cumsum()[~mask].reset_index(name='new')
          .groupby(['court_name','new'])['level_1']
          .agg(['min','max'])
          .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

#change by subtract and add 1 hour if not 7:00 and 23:00
df['min'] = df['min'].where(df['min'].dt.hour.eq(7), df['min'] - pd.Timedelta('1H'))
df['max'] = df['max'].where(df['max'].dt.hour.eq(23), df['max'] + pd.Timedelta('1H'))

print (df)
                           min                 max
court_name                                        
Court 1    2021-11-15 07:00:00 2021-11-15 08:00:00
Court 1    2021-11-15 12:00:00 2021-11-15 15:00:00
Court 1    2021-11-15 21:00:00 2021-11-15 23:00:00
Court 2    2021-11-15 07:00:00 2021-11-15 20:00:00
Court 2    2021-11-15 21:00:00 2021-11-15 23:00:00
```

Comment: @user3225309 - You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

## Using `pandas`'s built-in `pd.DatetimeIndex` features

- Here's a short solution I think works quite well to utilize the existing `pandas` DatetimeIndex series functionalities most tersely.
- This solution assumes one-hour slot reservations, and that you meant it closes at 11pm sharp (so e.g. no one could book say 11pm-midnight, just to be super clear - hence you'll see I set the date ranges to end instead actually on the 22nd hour).

#### 1) Create new column "reserved_hours" of dtype `pd.DatetimeIndex` for all reservations (per court)

> *Note*: This introduces a list trickiness, easily handled though, where we will have to later on ensure we combine and remove dupes from all such lists of reservations (stored as `pd.DatetimeIndex` objects) - such functionality is totally built-in to pandas already

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

df["reserved_hours"] = [
    pd.date_range(df.loc[i, "reserved_fr"], df.loc[i, "reserved_to"], freq="H")
    for i in range(df.shape[0])
]
df
```

|  | court_name | reserved_fr | reserved_to | reserved_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Court 1 | 2021-11-15T08:00:00 | 2021-11-15T12:00:00 | DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 08:00:00', '2021-11-15 09:00:00', |
|  |  |  |  | '2021-11-15 10:00:00', '2021-11-15 11:00:00', |
|  |  |  |  | '2021-11-15 12:00:00'], |
|  |  |  |  | dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') |
| 1 | Court 1 | 2021-11-15T15:00:00 | 2021-11-15T16:00:00 | DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 15:00:00', '2021-11-15 16:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') |
| 2 | Court 1 | 2021-11-15T16:00:00 | 2021-11-15T21:00:00 | DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 16:00:00', '2021-11-15 17:00:00', |
|  |  |  |  | '2021-11-15 18:00:00', '2021-11-15 19:00:00', |
|  |  |  |  | '2021-11-15 20:00:00', '2021-11-15 21:00:00'], |
|  |  |  |  | dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') |
| 3 | Court 2 | 2021-11-15T20:00:00 | 2021-11-15T21:00:00 | DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 20:00:00', '2021-11-15 21:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') |

#### 2) Create a `pd.DatetimeIndex` which includes all possible one-hour slots

```py
available_hours = pd.date_range("2021-11-15T07:00:00",
                                "2021-11-15T22:00:00",
                                freq="H")
available_hours
```

> ````
> DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 07:00:00', '2021-11-15 08:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 09:00:00', '2021-11-15 10:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 11:00:00', '2021-11-15 12:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 13:00:00', '2021-11-15 14:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 15:00:00', '2021-11-15 16:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 17:00:00', '2021-11-15 18:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 19:00:00', '2021-11-15 20:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 21:00:00', '2021-11-15 22:00:00'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') ```
> ````

#### 3) Finally, use the built-in `pd.DatetimeIndex.difference` method to calculate remaining open one-hour slots

Because it's possible (and likely) *some* courts will have multiple datetime indeces, and thus, a list of `pd.DatetimeIndex` objects, we must first flatten such lists of lists, hence the use of `chain` below and the resetting of `pd.DatatimeIndex`.

```py
reserved_hours = df.groupby("court_name").reserved_hours.apply(list)
available = {
    court: available_hours.difference(
        pd.DatetimeIndex(list(chain.from_iterable(res))))
    for court, res in reserved_hours.to_dict().items()
}
print('\n\n'.join(map(str, list(available.items()))))
```

> ```
> ('Court 1', DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 07:00:00', '2021-11-15 13:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 14:00:00', '2021-11-15 22:00:00'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None))
>
> ('Court 2', DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 07:00:00', '2021-11-15
> 08:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 09:00:00', '2021-11-15 10:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 11:00:00', '2021-11-15 12:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 13:00:00', '2021-11-15 14:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 15:00:00', '2021-11-15 16:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 17:00:00', '2021-11-15 18:00:00',
>                '2021-11-15 19:00:00', '2021-11-15 22:00:00'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None))
> ```

So now we've ended up with a neat dictionary where the courts are the keys, and the values are all currently available *hour long* slots per court. For example the final available reservation slot of any day is the 22nd hour's slot (i.e., up until closing time).

---

### Re-create dict into dataframe showing all available one-hour slots as a datetime index

I think this method may make it easiest to then just list each item from the indeces, but of course further editing like windowing/collapsing together consecutive hours etc. could be done here.

```py
df_open = pd.DataFrame([(court, time) for court, time in available.items()],
                       columns=["court", "availabilities"])
df_open.set_index("court")
```

| court | availabilities |
| --- | --- |
| Court 1 | DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 07:00:00', '2021-11-15 13:00:00', '2021-11-15 14:00:00', '2021-11-15 22:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) |
| Court 2 | DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-15 07:00:00', '2021-11-15 08:00:00', '2021-11-15 09:00:00', '2021-11-15 10:00:00', '2021-11-15 11:00:00', '2021-11-15 12:00:00', '2021-11-15 13:00:00', '2021-11-15 14:00:00', '2021-11-15 15:00:00', '2021-11-15 16:00:00', '2021-11-15 17:00:00', '2021-11-15 18:00:00', '2021-11-15 19:00:00', '2021-11-15 22:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) |